# PHP - Execute function after you've been redirected

Tags: php, function, post, redirect

I'm trying to create a login on `login.php`. When I submit, I redirect to the file `validaton.php`.

Now, I check if the username and the password is existing in my database with a simple function like this (there's more but that's what my question is about):

> validation.php

```
$result =  $conn->query('SELECT * FROM db WHERE username  = '.$username.' AND password = '.$password);

if ($result->num_rows == 1){
  //Continue
  header("Location: welcome.php");
} else {
  // Go back to Login
  header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Let's say the user doesn't exist and the else-statement will be executed.

**Is there a way to execute a function in `login.php` directly after I've been redirected from `validation.php`?**

For example, I'd like to alert "This user doesn't exist!" on `login.php` after the redirect.

> login.php

```
if(redirect happened){
  alert("This user doesn't exist!");
}
```

It's difficult to explain my question in English but I tried my best and any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: take a look into the $_SESSION variable :)

Comment: What do you mean exactly? @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: you can put a `$_SESSION['redirected_to_login'] = true;` before you're redirect, then on your login page you can do `if ($_SESSION['redirect_to_login']) {//some code}` http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Yeah you're right, just like @Rahul's answer. But you forgot the isset right?

Comment: yes and no - yes as in it's good to have and good practice to use and no as in, it's not actually required to use but definitely do use it. I was just giving an example :) and in this case you wouldn't have the isset because in my case it's a boolean so it only checks if it's true which can only happen if it's been set to true :)

Comment: Ah forgot about the boolean :D excuse my newbieness  @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: no problem :) happy codin' :D

Comment: Happy codin' :D @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible. You need to append a parameter in your header().

Here is how you can do this:

```
$result =  $conn->query('SELECT * FROM db WHERE username  = '.$username.' AND password = '.$password);

if ($result->num_rows == 1){
  //Continue
  header("Location: welcome.php");
} else {
  // Go back to Login
  header("Location: login.php?redirect=1");
}
```

Now, you can check:

```
if($_GET['redirect'] == 1) {
 // redirect happened. execute some code or JS here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Wow, that easy... but I never thought about this... :)

Comment: this will throw an error when redirect parameter is not given.. you may want to check if the parameter is given like below:
if (isset($_GET['redirect'])) {
   if ($_GET['redirect'] == 1) {
         //then your code
   }
}

Comment: Thanks ;) I'd be glad if you could edit your answer and insert Rahul's answer for the people who pass by (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280223/php-execute-function-after-youve-been-redirected?noredirect=1#answer-44280359)

Answer (score 2):

You could use session as

**validation.php**

```
session_start();
$result =  $conn->query('SELECT * FROM db WHERE username  = '.$username.' AND password = '.$password);

if ($result->num_rows == 1){
  //Continue
  header("Location: welcome.php");
} else {
  // Go back to Login
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "User not found";
  header("Location: login.php");
}
```

in **login.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
{
  // code for show message
}
```

Comment: I destroy the session in the login.php after my code with `session_destroy();` to avoid an unnecessary problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many options for you. The most basic one is using a GET-Request. For example you could use something like:

`header("Location: login.php?exist=no");
die();`

and on your login page you can receive that parameter by using something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['exist']) && $_GET['exist'] === 'no'){
   echo "User does not exist!";
}
```